# Angular 6 RxJS6 Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs6

I am converting my code to use RxJS6 syntax to use pipe and map but I am getting error.

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '(error: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err:
any, caught: Observable<void>) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
```

The existing code works fine but the issue I have is that before result is returned, other methods get called. So to my understanding using pipe and map 
will resolve this issue.
Here is the code I had initially:

```
this._reportingService.GetProjectReportsData(data).subscribe(result => {
    if (result != null) {
        this.reportData = result;
    }

}, error => {
    this.ErrorMessage('Unable to load workbook ' + error.toString());
    this._reportingService.isLoading = false;
});
```

Here is the code I am trying to convert to using pipe and map:

I have imported along with rest of imports

```
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

and in the method(modified; removed this.error) Please guide how to add code for errorMessage:

```
this._reportingService.GetProjectReportsData(data).pipe(
    map(result => {
        if (result != null) {

  this.reportData = result;


        }
    }))
    .subscribe();
```

And my service class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

import { map, tap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ReportingService extends BehaviorSubject<any[]>{

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    super(null);
    }

    public GetProjectReportsData(data: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post(this.GetProjectReportDataUrl, data)
            .pipe(map(res => <any[]>res))
            .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    }
    private handleError(error: any) {

        let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
            error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is due to that you are missing the return statement in the `map` operator.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

this._reportingService.GetProjectReportsData(data).pipe(
    map(result => {
        if (result != null) {
           return this.reportData = result;
        }
        return of(null);
    }))
    .subscribe();
```

Also not sure why you are using this validation, (result != null). Just be carefull there.

Answer (score 1):

According to me double pipe chaining creates the problem.

try like this.

```
 public GetProjectReportsData(data: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post(this.GetProjectReportDataUrl, data)
            .pipe(
               map(res => <any[]>res),
               catchError(this.handleError)
             );
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Return observable from `catchError`:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

...
catchError(error => of(this.ErrorMessage('Unable to load workbook ' + error.toString()))
...
```

Comment: Can you please suggest the whole block? Not getting correct syntax...getting number of squiggles.

Comment: modified code and removed this.ErrorMessage. Code compiles fine. But still need to know how to add code for this.ErrorMessage